# Image replacing using upload preview in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip in my project. The image showing in edit form, but i want to change that uploaded image instead of new image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#my_image')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(100)
                    .height(100);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```